# Customise the text in the UIActivityViewController when using SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiactivityviewcontroller, sfsafariviewcontroller

I have a simple application that loads web pages within the app where on iOS 8, I am using a custom `UIWebViewController` called `VideoWebViewController` and for iOS 9, I'm using `SFSafariViewController`. Within the `VideoWebViewController`, I have the following method which gets called when the `UIActivityViewController` is being called:

```
NSString *currentURL = self.webView.request.URL.absoluteString;
// This method gets called when the user hits the right bar button item; the share sheet.
NSURL *facebook = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com"];
NSURL *twitter = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://twitter.com"];
NSString *forwardedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Check this out %@, %@", facebook, twitter];
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = nil;
activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:forwardedString, nil] applicationActivities:nil];
```

When I call the `VideoWebViewController`, I am doing it this way:

```
VideoWebViewController *video = [[VideoWebViewController alloc] init];
        UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:video];
        [self presentViewController:navigation animated:YES completion:nil];
        [video setSelectedVideo:@"https://www.youtube.com"];
```

When I call the `SFSafariViewController`, I am doing it this way:

```
SFSafariViewController *safariVC = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com/"]entersReaderIfAvailable:NO];
safariVC.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:safariVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Issue**

So how exactly do I customise the text of when the `UIActivityViewController` is called in the `SFSafariViewController`? It's easy to do that with the `VideoWebViewController` because I am setting a custom subclass, but I'm not sure if there's a way to do that with `SFSafariViewController`? When the user selects the Share Sheet (UIActivityViewController) in the `SFSafariViewController`, I just want to add some custom text.

**Update**

I have created a custom subclass of SFSafariViewController, but I can't see a way to invoke the method of what happens when the user selects the ShareSheet (UIActivityViewController).

Any guidance on this would be appreciated.

**Update**

It doesn't look like this is possible, so I have created a bug report with Apple for this: https://bugreport.apple.com/problem/viewproblem